# If $A\in M_{mn}(\mathbb F)$, write an equation relating $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ and $\operatorname{dim(ker}(A))$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

dim = dimensions and ker = kernel

I know how to obtain the kernel of a matrix and the rank as well, but the thing that is throwing me off is to write down an equation that relates the dimensions of the kernel and the rank of the matrix.

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you know about the rank nullity theorem? Also, what does the rank of a matrix signify ? What is the dimension of the image ?

Comment: For a linear map from $T: V \rightarrow W$, $dim (V) = rank (T) + nullity(T)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a matrix $A$ has $n$ columns then $Rank (A) + \dim{(\ker{(A)})} = n$

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to check out rank nullity theorem.

To understand it.

Consider the RREF, there are pivot columns and non-pivot columns.

The number of pivot columns is the rank of the matrix, each non-zero rows have a leading $1$ and they are linearly independent.

Recall that when we solve for the nullspace. We would introduce parameters for the variables corresponds to non-pivot columns. Hence the number of non-pivot columns correspond to the nullity.

Hence, rank + nullity = number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

The rank of a matrix is the dimension of the image, and the nullity is the dimension of the kernel. The rank-nullity theorem states that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $T \in L(V)$ which has an associate matrix respect to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ then $$ rank(A)+null(A)=\dim( V).$$